# Output same produced file to several output locations

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am using XSLT (triggered from terminal) to build 2 separate XHTML documents in their own folder structure (e.g. "doc-1-folder", "doc-2-folder"). Each time I build I would like to have a "local" output, but I also added a shared storage folder where I want the outputs to also arrive.

Each trigger of XSLT should therefor produce same output file twice,
one to its local folder and one to shared folder.

The reason for wanting to have duplicate of document builds, is that I will merge some document and would like to perform the merge calling the storage folder.

A short illustration:

**Production of doc-1:**

```
/doc-1-folder/myDoc-1.xhtml
/shared/storage/myDoc-1.xhtml
```

**Production of doc-2:**

```
/doc-2-folder/myDoc-2.xhtml
/shared/storage/myDoc-2.xhtml
```

**Would in storage generate:**

```
/shared/storage/myDoc-1.xhtml
/shared/storage/myDoc-2.xhtml
```

Reading here:
https://www.saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!using-xsl/commandline,
it looks like one can only define one output file with the flag "-o".

Is it possible to define several output files? Or would I have to create several XSLT script to process the (identical) output twice?

Comment: You can use the [xsl:result-document](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#creating-result-trees) instruction to create multiple result documents from a single XSL transformation.

Comment: Makes sense. Tested to add the xsl:result-document at the bottom of my principal.xsl, since I build in a modular way. There was no error during XSLT transformation but the produced document (to secondary location, storage) came out blank. Probably I am missing some syntax part or code that should be within the xsl:result-document tags.

Comment: You need to make sure you populate your result documents e.g. `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:result-document href="result1.xml"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:result-document><xsl:result-document href="result2.xml"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:result-document></xsl:template>`

Comment: If you want a copy of your main result, then produce the output in a variable first. Then copy the variable to both the main output and the  `xsl:result-document`  element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this all within XSLT, you could use the logic

```
<xsl:variable name="outputDoc">
  ... generate the output ...
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:result-document href="firstOutput.xml">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$outputDoc"/>
</xsl:result-document>
<xsl:result-document href="secondOutput.xml">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$outputDoc"/>
</xsl:result-document>
```

If you're using the Java API for Saxon (s9api) you could be a bit more adventurous and a bit more efficient by writing a `ResultDocumentHandler` that directs the output to a `net.sf.saxon.s9api.TeeDestination` that directs it to two separate places on the fly.

Comment: Understood, is it mandatory to keep xsl:output or could I theoretically use only xsl:result-document to produce primary and secondary document output?

Comment: You can always produce a "dummy" primary output if you want. You can also use xsl:result-document with no @href to define the format of the primary output dynamically.